# How to setup and use oled SSD1306 I2C screen(UG-2864HSWEG01) in proteus 8.8

Tags: arduino, proteus, oled

i am trying to simulate an 128 x 64 I2C oled screen with arduino but cannot get to work.

I am using the arduino compiler and the libraries adafruit gfx 1.1.5 and adafruit ssd1306 1.1.2 ( light size instead modern ones )

I have tried some codes and the companion examples in hex format but it does not work.

Also I have tried finding the oled the I2C address and no I2C devices found.

## UPDATED and solved.

My references

[OLED Datasheet](https://www.codico.com/shop/media/datasheets/UG-2864HSWEG01.pdf)

[Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf4eVzgiNzg&ab_channel=SatyamSingh)

The current schema

My example code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include<SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

void setup()
{

Serial.begin(9600);
display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3D);
display.display();
delay(2000);
display.clearDisplay();

display.drawPixel(40, 10, WHITE);
display.drawPixel(50, 10, WHITE);
display.drawPixel(60, 10, WHITE);
display.display();
delay(2000);

}

void loop()
{
delay(100);
}
```

[image: current schematic]

Comment: Debugging questions needs to include meaningful indication of the failure - so for example, this is an I2C interface, are bus operations getting an ACK?.  You have the additional issue here that it's not really knowable if the *simulation* is true to what it purports to model in all cases - it's entirely possible that something that works in the hardware won't in the simulator.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include a solution. If it has the property of an answer to your question, **add it as answer**! It's encouraged to answer your own questions here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah, ok

Comment: Instead of adding `[SOLVED]` to the question, please accept the correct answer.

Comment: Please make you own answer and mark it as "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema was right. I am using I2C interface.

Later I with the comment i discovered the I2C debugger and see what was going wrong.
The bus connection was not set up properly.

Once corrected all works as expected.

[image]